# xcode -22421 error when uploading app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

when uploading my app to app store , like always (-> archive then upload) , I see 'xcode' is trying to download something about "Java".
so I downloaded java and installed it. 
and when i upload again ,it still downloading something about "Java" but suddenly it stops and show this error :

[image: error screenshot]

so , how can i fix it ?

Comment: Clean , build again and try  to upload again. If that doesn't work try using Application Loader. PS - you are not alone . lot of users are getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

This means, that Apple servers may not be working properly at the moment. Just try to upload your app later.